# After installing and then removing Google Apps from my website, entering the URL without "www" no longer works

Tags: google, dns, google-workspace

A few days ago I added Google Apps to my site to try it out and see how I liked it. However, it wasn't really going to fit my needs, so I decided to remove it earlier this morning.

Before I installed Google Apps I was able to type in "www.mysite.com" or just "mysite.com" and get to the same place. However, after installing GApps and removing them, just typing in "mysite.com" no longer works. "www.mysite.com" works fine, though. I think GApps may have broken my URL, but maybe it just takes a few days to propagate the changes. Do any of you have any experience with this or know if the GApps (or removal of GApps) changes take awhile to go into effect?

The error that I get when I just type in "mysite.com" is the following:

Google Error

404 - Not found. The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Also, for the record, I cannot SSH/SFTP in to "mysite.com", but I can do so to "www.mysite.com" Not sure if this helps, but I figure the more information the better.

Comment: What steps did you do when removing Google Apps from your domain?

Comment: I went to the Google Apps Dashboard and clicked "Remove Apps from my Site" and continued through the process. Then I went back to my hosts control panel and reconfigured the settings there so that the host was handling all hosting and DNS services. I also checked a box in my hosts control panel that says "Resolve http://mysite.com and http://www.mysite.com to the same place" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

I think given that the error message comes from Google you need to wait until the DNS changes have propagated and Google no longer have anything to do with the domain.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'm just a little new to this whole webmaster gig, so I'm trying to get my bearings regarding how all of this stuff works.